# SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: spring, spring-boot, native

I want to execute following query:

```java
@Query(value = "select * from wash_history w where w.wash_id IN \n"
        + "(select w.id from wash w where w.car_wash_id=?1) order BY w.time 
?2", nativeQuery = true)
List<WashHistory> findDesc(Integer carWashId,String descOrAsc);
```

But I have the following error

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
```

How can I choose between `desc` or `ac` in this query?

Comment: Add the full stack trace. Also placeholders in the order by query generally aren't supported (although it might differ based on your JDBC driver). To order there is the `Sort` class which you can pass as the last argument of your method.

Comment: Thank man , but what about the following query ,  @Query(value = "update car_wash  set lon_lat=ST_GeomFromText('POINT(:lon :lat)')where id=:id;",nativeQuery = true)
void upateLonLat(Double lon,Double lat,Integer id);
I need to know how to put params to query, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: That is a different question. Also why would you need that update query? Beats the purpose of having JPA in the first place, looks like you are working around JPA instead of using JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to use `Pageable` with native queries. Spring data will append to the end of your request " order by " if there is a `Sort` object in the `Pageable`.

```
List<WashHistory> findDesc(Integer carWashId,String descOrAsc, Pageable pageable);
```